# Paytm Payment Gateway In React JS

Tags: reactjs, redux, payment-gateway, paytm

I am working on my First react js project. I need to integrate Paytm payment gateway. I can't seem to find any proper documentation or procedure for React js on their website.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Paytm `jsCheckout` solution which has [documentation on their website here](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/js-checkout/).

The docs have a [solution recommender](https://business.paytm.com/docs/recommendations) too which can help show you which different options are available for the project you are trying to complete.

This is the link to the [main docs page](https://business.paytm.com/docs).

As for an example, there is a [sample React integration you can find on GitHub](https://github.com/paytm/paytm-blink-checkout-react).